# how do I interact with the inferior prolog process in emacs?

Tags: emacs, prolog, read-eval-print-loop, swi-prolog

I've installed SWI-Prolog and Emacs' prolog mode.  I have a `first_steps.pl` file with prolog in it, and I do `C-c C-b` to consult the buffer.  This opens a second buffer, `*prolog*`, whose mode is `(Inferior Prolog: run)`.

All well and good.  However, it's completely unclear how to interact with that inferior prolog mode buffer.  There is no prompt.  Typing things and pressing return does nothing.  How can I execute queries based on the code consulted from the buffer, i.e, interact with SWI-prolog?

Note that this related question does not seem to address usage of the inferior mode, only installation of prolog mode:
[Using prolog with emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288024/using-prolog-with-emacs)

Comment: It's hard to tell the exact nature of the problem, but please confirm that you see something like this in the inferior Prolog buffer: `?- % /tmp/prolcomp18321k_m.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
true.`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I see that, but in the emacs command buffer, not the prolog buffer.  The prolog buffer remains blank.  It wrote it to var/folders/....

Comment: I think for this one you need to find somebody who can look over your shoulder and see what's going on with the screen while you're using it.

Comment: You should have two buffers: one file buffer in Prolog mode and one inferior prolog buffer. You'll type your code in the file buffer but then interactively query the inferior prolog buffer. C-c C-b throws you into the inferior prolog buffer so you should be able to just type a query after that and get a response.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I am doing that, but the inferior prolog window doesn't do anything in response to the things I type there, and it's not clear what the incantation is.  In the file buffer, I have a definition for a conc predicate (list concatentation).  I do C-c C-b, and that says that it wrote the temp file, and puts me in the inferior buffer.  In the inferior buffer, I type conc([], [], L). and press enter.  Nothing happens.  There's also no prompt.  Is there a special key sequence to get it to process what I typed as a query?

Comment: On my computer, it either works fine, or it says it couldn't launch Prolog. It never silently fails. Hence, I think you need in-person help.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Could you tell me what you see in the inferior process?  Does it just give you a prompt like the command-line swipl program?

Comment: More or less: `Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.2.2)
Copyright (c) 1990-2012 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- % /tmp/prolcomp12345C2y.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
true.`

Comment: There are some newlines in there but that's the gist of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29610/discussion-between-daniel-lyons-and-jake)

Comment: Ah I see.  So mine is definitely just failing to start up silently.  Ok, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Enter the chatroom, maybe we can beat it into working...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the variable `prolog-program-name` to use the full path to my `swipl` executable, then it was fine.  Emacs might just not be able to find your interpreter.