# Cannot edit "Prolog Program Name" on SWI-Prolog with GNU-Emacs (trying to setup inferior Prolog process)

Tags: emacs, configuration, windows-8, swi-prolog, emacs24

I am on Windows 8, I like Emacs and wish to use it for Prolog programming. I am trying to set up an inferior Prolog process from which to query Prolog programs.

I am following [this installation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/GnuEmacs.html).
I have successfully followed steps 1 (saved on `C:\Users\Username\Emacs-24.3\site-lisp`), 2, 3, and some of 4. But I cannot

> Go to "Prolog Inferior" group and edit "Prolog Program Name", to insert SWI Prolog's
> command pathname
> as there is no edit option to be found.

My question:

- how to edit `prolog-program-name`, or
- how to insert SWI Prolog's command pathname, or
- how to set up an inferior Prolog process on emacs ?

Thank you!

Comment: by the way, this discussion did not help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424293/how-do-i-interact-with-the-inferior-prolog-process-in-emacs)

Comment: What it's trying to say is that you need to `M-x customize-group RET prolog`, and I think you'll figure it out from there.

Comment: Emacs-24.3 already comes with a more recent version of prolog.el than the one from http://turing.ubishops.ca/home/bruda/emacs-prolog.  So step 1 and 2 are not needed.  Step 3 is buggy: it should use `"\\.pl\\'"` rather than `"\\.pl"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `swipl` is in your $PATH, you don't need any customization at all.  But otherwise, just use the built-in prolog-mode and add something like `(setq prolog-program-name "c:/Users/Username/SWI-Prolog/swipl")`.  Note the use of forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this is what worked for me.  This is on Emacs 26.3. After upgrading all my packages, `C-c C-b` in Prolog buffers had changed its behaviour into running GNU Prolog by default.  Under `Prolog Program Name`, which appears to be a dictionary, there is a key `t` which was set to `gprolog`. So I set it to `swipl` as highlighted in the screenshot, and got back the previous/desired behaviour.

[image: screenshot]